# Python: escribir una función que reciba una cadena y devuelva un diccionario con las primeras letras de la cadena

Tags: python

me encuentro con el siguiente problema que se me esta haciendo difícil resolver:
Escribir una función que reciba por parámetro una cadena y devuelva un diccionario cuyas claves sean las primeras letras de cada palabra y cuyo valor asociado sea una lista de palabras que empiezan con cada letra. 
Por ejemplo, si recibe: `'Este es el día del trabajador`. Debe devolver: `{'d':['del','día'], 'e':['este','es','el'],'t':['trabajador']}`
No olvidar el .lower()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahí va:

```
def stringtoDict(cadena):
    diccionario = dict()
    cadena = cadena.lower()
    lista = cadena.split()
    for palabra in lista:
        diccionario.setdefault(palabra[0], [])
        diccionario[palabra[0]].append(palabra)

    return diccionario
```

Podrías escribir el setdefault con la palabra como valor a la clave, siempre y cuando la metieras en una lista, pero te recomiendo hacerlo así.

El setdefault lo que está haciendo es comprobar si existe esa clave, y si no existe la crea con una lista vacía. Luego tienes que hacer el append del elemento que quieres añadir. Ten en cuenta que si quitas la segunda línea y añades la palabra en el set default, solo se añadirán las primera palabra de cada clave.